# Flot chart points.show:false does not work

Tags: jquery, flot

I am using flot charts (http://flotcharts.org) to build a graph in my app, but I encountered a problem to which I couldn't find solution anywhere. the `points.show:false` property doesn't seem to work, whereas `lines.show:false` works just fine.

I am using flot tooltip (https://github.com/krzysu/flot.tooltip) plugin to show the data for points on hover.

Here is a part of my code:

```
options = {
        series: {
          points: {
            show: false,
            lineWidth: 1,
            fill: true,
            fillColor: false,
            symbol: "circle",
            radius: 2
          },
          lines: {
            show: false
          },
          splines: {
            show: true
          }
          shadowSize: 5

        },
        legend:{
          container:$("#legendContainer") 
        },
        grid: {
          hoverable: true,
          clickable: false,
          show: true,
          backgroundColor: { colors: ["#f9f9f9","#ffffff"]}
        },
        colors:["#f63131","#f0cd48","#7ef048","#4888f0","#a84ad6","#ffa500"],
        tooltip: true,
        tooltipOpts: {
          defaultTheme: false,
          content: "%s <br> %x <br>%y"
        },
        xaxis:
          {
           mode: "time",
           minTickSize: [1, "day"],
           max: (new Date()).getTime(),
           min: minDate
          },
        yaxes:[
          { ticks: [] },
          { ticks: [] },
          { ticks: [] },
          { ticks: [] },
          { ticks: [] }
        ]

      };
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The

```
 points: {
      show: false
 }
```

controls whether points are drawn on the graph and [it works just fine with your options](http://jsfiddle.net/qn3F7/1/).

I believe the "points" you are referring to are when you hover over the plot and it highlights the point you are over.  [To disable that](https://github.com/flot/flot/blob/master/API.md#customizing-the-grid), set:

```
 grid: {
     autoHighlight: false
 }
```

Comment: Yeah, but when I use splines, the tooltip doesn't work when the points.show is set to false. :(

Comment: @SambhavSharma, since that's beyond the scope of this question, please open a new one with relevant details and I'll take a look.